# Can we install packages on teamcity agent

Tags: c#, docker, build, teamcity

The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.

> System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load shared library
> 'libgdiplus' or one of its dependencies

I am getting this error while running tests as one of the  teamcity build steps.I am not running them through docker. I have directly integrated tests into teamcity build steps.

I have found solutions which could be of help while running tests through docker

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libgdiplus libc6-dev
```

The above can be added to dockerfile.but in my case it doesnt work

Thanks in advance